# Key exists in table but shows Can't Drop foreign key in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE order_products" are

```
CREATE TABLE `order_products` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `amount` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
 `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `tax_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `discount_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `order_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `username` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `shop_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `order_products_product_id_foreign` (`product_id`),
 KEY `order_products_tax_id_foreign` (`tax_id`),
 KEY `order_products_discount_id_foreign` (`discount_id`),
 KEY `order_products_order_id_foreign` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And i try to delete my key "order_products_product_id_foreign" by

```
ALTER TABLE order_products DROP FOREIGN KEY order_products_product_id_foreign
```

But it gives me error

```
#1091 - Can't DROP 'order_products_product_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists
```

Comment: It's not a _foreign_ key

Comment: Thanks i got it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the FOREIGN KEY keyword here.

```
alter table order_products drop key order_products_product_id_foreign;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a foreign key. so execute the line.

```
ALTER TABLE order_products DROP KEY order_products_product_id_foreign
```